# Content blocker (adblocker) for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone-app, ad-blocker

I'm looking for a content blocker, or failing that an adblocker for iPhone 5.

Now I wouldn't ask this question here without a little research. All the adblockers (free of charge *and* paid) which I found required iOS 9.x (which I have) and an **iPhone 5s** (which I don't have). The important point is, that the iPhone 5s was - to my knowledge - the first iPhone with a 64-bit CPU. So aside from the fact that the app store will simply refuse to install anything not compatible with my device, there seems to be an actual underlying reason.

Can anyone here point out such software compatible with iPhone 5 and perhaps even down to iPhone 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adblock Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adblock-browser-best-ad-blocker/id1015653330) should work. It's completely free and it requires iOS 8.0+ (so it's not compatible with iPhone 4, but it is with iPhone 5) and does not restrict usage to any specific iPhone/iPad/iPodTouch model. [Here the website](https://adblockbrowser.org/).

If you need something compatible with iPhone 4 you should try with [AdBlocker Browser with Chromecast Support since 2012](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adblock-for-iphone-ipad-ipod/id537774578?mt=8) which is free, but with paid pro features (like tabs), and it requires iOS 7.0+ without any model restriction. [Here the website](http://netzsuche.org/).